# How to use sqlite with entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

I am developing a desktop application that should save its data to a SQLite database. And I want to use Entity Framework code first to do that. But, I received error every time. This is my initial app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyPersonContext" connectionString="Data Source=ali.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and this is my context:

```
class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonContext() :
        base("name=MyPersonContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

and I receive this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233067
Message=Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installe    or registered in the application config.
Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
     at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderFactoryExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbProviderFactory factory)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultInvariantNameResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
     at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection connection)
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ...:line 51
     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
     at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID    Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
     at WindowsFormsApplication2.Program.Main() in ...:line 19
     at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
     at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

I searched about 5 hours, and editted app.config multiple times. But I still can not save my data to db.

Comment: I have some tips here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html - also see the comments

Comment: Can you explain your  question explicitely?